# Jquery autocomplete submission form

Tags: php, jquery, input

I am converting an old double dropdown box search form. With the old method, the form was submitted on each user selection using this:

```
<form name="navTwo">
<select name="item" id="item" onChange="document.location.href=document.navTwo.game.options[document.navTwo.game.selectedIndex].value">
```

The problem with the old method is that users were forced to look thru the second dropdown that contained an ever growing number of options.

I opted to make a new search using one auto submit drop down and a new jquery type ahead search field (thanks to Jamie McConnell, jamie@blue44.com). Everything works great with the type ahead. However, I cannot figure out how to submit the new form once the user picks the type ahead item. Ideally I would like to force the user to click submit once they've selected that second item.

I've tried carrying the id of the second search item and placing it in a hidden input but I cannot get the variable set to the id. Here is what I've tried so far, unsuccessfully;

//The page name is dash3.php
//If list = 1 it will add the record
//The jquery stuff works fine, it adds the value to the input field, I need it to grab the id of that record, not just the title. The $vid is empty, not sure how to set it.
//The code below is missing the submit button, I tried adding a link so that I could see the variables.

```
<form name="nav">
 <div>
   Start typing the name of the item, select the correct title when it appears:<br />
   <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
   <input type="hidden" value="?list=1&ptfm_ctrl=1&vid=<?=$vid?>" />
 </div>

 <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
 <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
 <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">&nbsp;
 </div>
 </div>
<a href="dash3.php?list=1&hid=<?=$hid?>&vid=<?=$vid?>"><strong>+</strong></a>
</form>
```

So, to make my question more clear;

How can I grab the id of the type ahead record that is being placed in the input field by a jquery autocomplete script and make a self referencing form carrying this id to the same page?

Thanks much!

Comment: hi Steve, please post the jQuery/javascript code you are using for autocomplete

Comment: Here is the code I grabbed...http://www.nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example in the autocomplete documentation will help: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

The idea is that you populate your autocomplete boxes with enough data for the user to select the right choice and then provide the `id` and hook into the `success` event.

```
select: function( event, ui ) { ... }
```

This might help get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/HGF59/

Instead of the alert that fires upon the second dropdown selection, do something like update your form action:

```
$("#myForm").attr("action", $("#myForm").attr("action") + "/" + ui.item.id);
```

and then submit if needed.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Great resource referenced there...add something new to the list have to learn to get this done! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, but only with another! I have no clue how to code this but I'm working with some other examples that you directed me to. Thanks!